Does wave superposition implies energy conservation?
Imagine a scenario in which two exactly identical but opposite sine wave (basically shifted by a phase of Pi) are superimposing. My question is why isn't the energy conserved here. I mean both the waves had an amplitude of A therefore having K(A*A) but the resultant wave has zero energy which means energy is lost between the two waves.

This question is similar to: What happens to the energy when waves perfectly cancel each other?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Destructive interference of electromagnetic and mechanical waves
